# Azure DevOps reorder work items in query result

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way I can reorder work items from a query results as I would normally do with backlog work items?

I'm using the order of work items in the backlog to set the order of issues to address, I would like to use queries to view work items by certain criteria (cross-project) so the backlog board is not a good choice for me.

thank

Answer (score 2):

The description is little confusing, but if you just want to order your query result(according to the title of this thread) by specific condition, the wiql would be very helpful.

Add the [Wiql Editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) to your organization, then create a query with the other conditions you need, click the "Edit query wiql" and update the query wiql.

[image]

For information about wiql syntax, please check [Syntax for the Work Item Query Language (WIQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops), the [order by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops#sort-results-order-by) would be the one you are looking for.

Comment: Is this what you want and is it helpful? You can accept it as the answer if it helps or please feel free to follow if there are other concerns. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Yang for your reply,
using "wiql" or just sorting by column will not due cause I need somehow to fix the data by feed values from the users, so assuming you will suggest adding a new field to sort by it, which is quite possible, it will require some way to automatically reorder all other work items in the result (of the query) when this field gets updated.

BTW, I used the term "reorder" just because it is the same action done in the backlog work items when reordering them (which is the same idea I'm trying to do here).

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "fix the data by feed values from the users", is this "feed value from users" some kind of custom field? I mean, if you want to order your query result data, then it should be during the query process as an `order by` condition rather than reorder the data after the query is completed, right? Sorry i haven't got the point still.

Comment: "fix the data by feed values from the users" - the presented work items order determines/defined by the users, the query job here is just to present them in the right order.

reordering is the process of the users to determine the order in which the result list needs to consumed/addressed.
reordering is done before the query executed.

Comment: I totally understand what's the requirement. And yes as you mentioned, i would suggest to add a new custom field to set your work items' order. But this method is not good, since you can only add custom fields to custom work item type and you will always have default items like tasks or bugs which you can not customize and this makes the reorder thing can only partialy work. I would say this is not possible at current time, maybe you can [suggest this uservoice here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?sort=votes&type=idea&openOnly=true).

Comment: this works and should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have queried the results, and you have the table with your results in it, you can click the column header to sort the results . . .
Once you Save the query, it seems to save the sort order that was selected in the results.

[image]